# R: Change the fields' (slots') values of the class assigning a value to some other field

Tags: r, reference-class

Assgning a value to one field, how can I make the other fields changing.

Consider the following `ReferenceClass` object:

```
C<-setRefClass("C", 
      fields=list(a="numeric",b="numeric")
      , methods=list(
      seta = function(x){
      a<<-x
      b<<-x+10
      cat("The change took place!")
      }
      ) # end of the methods list
      ) # end of the class
```

Now create the instance of the class

```
c<-C$new()
```

This command

```
c$seta(10)
```

will result in that c$a is 10 and c$b is 20.

So it actually works, however, **I want to achieve this result by the command**

```
c$a<-10
```

(i.e. after that I want c$b to be equal to 20 as defined in the class in the logic of seta() function)
How can I do it?

Comment: Oh no!  It's not an R5 class! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137199/what-is-the-significance-of-the-new-reference-classes

Comment: it follows that the proper name is actually "Reference Class", right?

Comment: Exactly.  Unfortunately it's not as compact, but such is life.

Comment: to whom it may concern, please mention the reasons for which you downvote this question, this would help me to avoid posting inappropriate questions in the future.

Comment: it wasn't me who downvoted, but the question can be improved by adding [reference-class] tag to it, and editing `R5` class to `Reference Class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for *accessor functions*, which are described in detail in `?ReferenceClasses`. This should work:

```
C<-setRefClass("C", 
    fields=list(
        a=function(v) {
              if (missing(v)) return(x)
              assign('x',v,.self)                    
              b<<-v+10
              cat ('The change took place!')
            }
       ,b="numeric"
    )
    ,methods=list(
        initialize=function(...)  {
             assign('x',numeric(),.self)
            .self$initFields(...)
        } 
    )
)

c<-C$new()
c$a
# numeric(0)
c$a<-3
# The change took place!
c$b
# 13
c$a
# 3
```

It does have the side effect that a new value, `x` is now in the environment `c` (the class object), but it is 'hidden' from the user in the sense that just printing `c` will not list `x` as a field.

Comment: the command "c<-C$new()" results in the error message "Error in function (v)  : object 'x' not found"